# Is there a way to shrink a div overriding all the widths, margins, and paddings inside it? css

Tags: css, html, width

I have columns on both sides of my site with elements inside them with different widths, margins,and paddings. Is there a way to override all the inner stuff and set a width for the whole column?

`overflow:hidden;` and `!important` tags on the widths of the columns don't set it.

Answer (score 2):

If your widths are relative then "sort of". Absolute widths can't be set by outside elements.

For example, consider this markup:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner_1"></div>
    <div id="inner_2"></div>
</div>
```

If you have the inner divs set to percentage widths:

```
#inner_1 { width: 60%; }
#inner_2 { width: 40%; }
```

Then setting the width of the outer div will change them (a width of `400px` will make `inner_1` 240px and `inner_2` will be 160px; a width of `800px` will make them 480 and 320 etc)

However, if the widths are set like this:

```
#inner_1 { width: 300px; }
#inner_2 { width: 200px; }
```

then no, setting the with of `outer` will not change the inner widths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors to achieve that. For example you could use `#rightColumn * {/* your styles here */}` to set the properties for all elements inside you right column or `#rightColum .childSelector {/* your styles here */}` to set the styles for a group of elements/a single element that match the selector. Use !important to override any other styles if necessary.